# How can I control the Windows 7 mixer programmatically?

Tags: c#

Windows 7 has per-application volume controls that let you mute applications individually. How can I mute and unmute an application from a console app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the [IAudioSessionManager2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd370950%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) COM interface. Have a look at [Vista Core Audio API Master Volume Control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/CoreAudio.aspx?msg=2101011) that wraps some of the new [Core Audio APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd370784%28VS.85%29.aspx). The console project therein enumerates active audio sessions and lets you tweak volume and mute status of an active audio session.