# Finding Volume Value of Device in Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-8.1

I want to find the volume of the device "Speaker/Headphones(Realtek High Definition Audio)".

When you scroll the bar it gives you a value between 0/100, i want to be able to put that value into a variable to use it. I'm using visual studio 2013 and C# with windows 8.1.

Ive been searching and trying a load of different things but i cant seem to find the value of the device in the volume mixer. I've got a working app that can mute, turn up and turn down the volume.

Comment: I presume you're using the `WM_APPCOMMAND` for up/down/mute - You should look at [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221471/how-can-i-control-the-windows-7-mixer-programmatically) which point to examples that allow you to do this.

Comment: Thanks, that link goes to deleted post. The code i have uses the  IAudioSessionManager2 but i still cant output that single value. It was copied code and gave me the app name a load of numbers, but not the volume. Is there no simple way to get this one value ?